# Automatic check box selection in android custom listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

`I'm new to android and  building a list and the list contain installed app name with a CheckBox to chose which one to uninstall. for example, the problem is that when the list became longer than the phone screen and the scrolling is active; when i select a check box , a second one is automatically selected in the bottom of the list.

The problem is automatic checkbox selection of check boxes, plz help me.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ultimate, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();


            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appName);
            holder.apkInstall=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.appMemory);
            holder.cb=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);




            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        }


        PackageInfo  packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);
        Drawable appIcon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
        String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel( packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);


        holder.cb.setTag(position);
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: holder.cb.setChecked(sba.get(position)); why you did this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to maintain your checked checkbox status into a ArrayList of Model Class. And it will reflect into your adapter and then into list view. First make a model class like below,

```
public class Model{
 String name;
 int value; /* 0 -&gt; checkbox disable, 1 -&gt; checkbox enable */

 Model(String name, int value){
 this.name = name;
 this.value = value;
 }
 public String getName(){
 return this.name;
 }
 public int getValue(){
 return this.value;
 }

}
```

Then into your adapter make your code look like this,

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter&lt;Model&gt;{
 Model[] modelItems = null;
 Context context;
 public CustomAdapter(Context context, Model[] resource) {
 super(context,R.layout.row,resource);
 // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 this.context = context;
 this.modelItems = resource;
 }
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false); 
 TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
 name.setText(modelItems[position].getName());
 if(modelItems[position].getValue() == 1)
 cb.setChecked(true);
 else
 cb.setChecked(false);
 return convertView;
 }
}
```

Now from your activity just pass your list of checkbox into adapter like below:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 modelItems = new Model[5];
 modelItems[0] = new Model("pizza", 0);
 modelItems[1] = new Model("burger", 1);
 modelItems[2] = new Model("olives", 1); 
 modelItems[3] = new Model("orange", 0); 
 modelItems[4] = new Model("tomato", 1); 
 CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, modelItems);
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now if user will checked/unchecked any checkbox just change the value in its model class and notify adapter.

Answer (score 1):

When you scroll a list view each time when it need to display a list view item it will call getView to creating or getting the layout. So you need to check whether it is checked or not using a boolean variable in model class and make the checkbox view as selected depending on the boolan value. You should update the boolean value of the model when user checks the checkbox.

Your model class should contain a variable which represent whether the checkbox is checked or not.

```
public class Model{
   .....
   boolean isChecked; //true if checkbox is checked
   .....
}
```

In your adapter class, inside getView().
You should check whether it is checked or not using the `isChecked` variable.

```
if(isChecked){
    holder.cb.setChecked(true);
} else {
    holder.cb.setChecked(false);
}
```